# Perl: How to get new directory made while unziping tar.gz files

Tags: linux, perl, compression, tar

I want to make a perl script that extracts a file, then opens the result and dose stuff in there.I have this code:

```
$res = qx{tar -xvf $tmp -C /tmp/}; #$tmp was specified earlier
```

but I don't know how to see what new directory was created?

This may not be the most efficient way, but I'm new to Perl and don't know all the modules.

Comment: You are expecting 'perl' to tell you something that a third-party product generates? well it won't happen unless you parse the output of the `tar` command and seek something like `/` and determine from that directories that were created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to parse the output of tar, which gets messy and can change between versions of tar.

Or you can untar in an empty directory.  Then whatever is in the directory after untaring is what came from the tarball.  This works even if the tarball is impolite and does not create a directory.

```
use File::Temp;

my $tempdir = File::Temp->newdir;
qx{tar -xvf $tarball -C $tempdir};
```

Or you can also use [Archive::Tar](https://metacpan.org/release/Archive-Tar) or [Archive::Extract](https://metacpan.org/release/Archive-Extract) to list the files in the archive.  Archive::Extract has the benefit of being a generic interface to all sorts of archive formats.

```
use Archive::Extract;

my $ae = Archive::Extract->new( archive => $tarball );
my $files = $ae->files;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a list of the directories you have before extracting the tarball (using readdir()), then regenerate it afterwards and deduce that anything that is in the new list and was not in the original list came from the tarball.